# DeployedAddresses + Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I have a contract like following -

**File Name: dummycontrat.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract DummyContract {

    function fetchRandomNumber() public pure returns(uint) {
        uint res = 10;
        return res;
    }

}
```

I have the following test file -

**FileName: test/TestDummyContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/dummycontract.sol";

    contract TestDummyContract {

        function testRandomNumberNew() public {
            DummyContract dummyContract = new DummyContract();
            uint randomNumber = dummyContract.fetchRandomNumber();
            Assert.equal(randomNumber, 10, "Number is not 10");
        }

        function testRandomNumberDeployed() public {
            DummyContract dummyContract = DummyContract(DeployedAddresses.DummyContract());
            uint randomNumber = dummyContract.fetchRandomNumber();
            Assert.equal(randomNumber, 10, "Number is not 10");
        }

    }
```

I run the command -

```
truffle compile && truffle migrate --reset --network dev && truffle test --network dev test/TestDummyContract.sol
```

The first test passes while the second gives an error. Logs from the `truffle test` command is following -

```
TestDummyContract
    ✓ testRandomNumberNew (53ms)
    1) testRandomNumberDeployed
    > No events were emitted


  1 passing (894ms)
  1 failing

  1) TestDummyContract testRandomNumberDeployed:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Can anyone explain what's the problem here? I am running Ganache tool on OSX for the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeployedAddresses.DummyContract()` is failing because only contracts that are included in the Truffle deployment configurations are made available to `DeployedAddresses`. From the [Truffle documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/solidity-tests#deployed-addresses):

> The addresses of your deployed contracts (i.e., contracts that were deployed as part of your migrations) are available through the truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol library. This is provided by Truffle and is recompiled and relinked before each suite is run to provide your tests with Truffle's a clean room environment. This library provides functions for all of your deployed contracts, in the form of:
>
> `DeployedAddresses.<contract name>();`

To fix your issue, you need to create the deployment configuration under /migrations (or add to your existing one, if you have it). For example:

**2_deploy_contracts.js**:

```
var DummyContract = artifacts.require("dummycontract");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(DummyContract);
};
```

Add that configuration, rerun `truffle migrate --reset` then your test will work.

Comment: Hello, I get similar error message for verifying Ethereum signature : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388045/verifying-ethereum-signature-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-rever) Thank you for any comment